# Concatenate various .txt and .html files to one .txt file in R

Tags: r, concatenation

I'm trying to write a script that automatically concatenates all files from specific folders automatically to one .txt file but I'm having problems because I'm trying to merge them into one big data frame before writing it into a txt file and I'm getting errors because column names didn't match, so I used smartbind, but not I'm getting an error for "double row names".

Here's my code:

```
library(gtools)

dir<-"/Users/max/Desktop/NISAT_All/Regions"

subdir_list<-list.dirs(dir, recursive=F) 
subdir_list<-list.dirs(subdir_list,  recursive=F)
as.matrix(subdir_list)
subdirs_General <- subdir_list[ grepl("General", subdir_list) ]
as.matrix(subdirs_General)
subdir_list <- subdir_list[ !grepl("General", subdir_list) ]
subdir_list<-list.dirs(subdir_list,  recursive=F)
as.matrix(subdir_list)


for (subdir in subdir_list){

  setwd(subdir)

  subdir <-list.files(subdir, recursive=T)
  files <- subdir[ grepl("Armed Groups and Small Guns", subdir) ]
  files <- c(files, subdir[ grepl("Arms Embargoes", subdir) ])
  files <- c(files, subdir[ grepl("Black Market", subdir) ])
  files <- c(files, subdir[ grepl("Brokering", subdir) ])
  files <- c(files, subdir[ grepl("Landmines", subdir) ])
  files <- c(files, subdir[ grepl("MANPADS", subdir) ])
  files <- c(files, subdir[ grepl("Production", subdir) ])
  files <- c(files, subdir[ grepl("Stockpile Security and Destruction", subdir) ])
  files <- c(files, subdir[ grepl("UN Processes", subdir) ])
  files <- c(files, subdir[ grepl("United Nations", subdir) ])
  files <- c(files, subdir[ grepl("Weapons Collection and Amnesties", subdir) ])

  dataframe <- data.frame()

  for (file in files){

      df_temp <- read.delim(file)
      dataframe <- smartbind(dataframe, df_temp, sep="\n")

  }
  #then write your final file
  write.table(dataframe,"MergedFiles.txt",sep="\n", row.names = F, eol = "\r")
  rm(dataframe)

}
```

on the picture you can see how the files usually look like, I just wanna merge them into one

Can anyone help?

[image: that's what the files usually look like]

[image: here's the latest error message]

Comment: Please do not post an image of errors (and code/data too, though not a factor here): it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: (1) Iteratively adding rows to a `data.frame` works logically, but its performance scales *horribly*: with each concatenation of rows, it makes a complete copy of the frame, meaning the first file is copied `n` times (if `n` files are loaded). (2) Row names cannot be duplicated when combining data, I suggest if the row names are meaningful, for each frame you should save them as a column of the frame itself, then clear the row names with `rownames(x) <- NULL`, and *then* performance the concatenation.

Comment: The file you show is a text file, is there a particular reason you're using `read.delim` instead of `readLines`?

Comment: Fundamentally, the `read.delim` is used to read *tabular data*, not text files. Use the appropriate function (`readLines`, as r2evans wrote).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have two text files to merge:

**test1.txt**

```
I'm not a pheasant plucker, I'm a pheasant plucker's son
```

**test2.txt**

```
and I'm only plucking pheasants til the pheasant plucker comes.
```

I just specify the names of the files I want to merge, and create an empty variable that will contain the merged contents:

```r
files_to_combine <- c(path.expand("~/test1.txt"), path.expand("~/test2.txt"))
combined <- ""
```

Now I just use `readLines()` to get the contents and paste them together.

```r
for (i in seq_along(files_to_combine))
{
  combined <- paste0(combined,  readLines(files_to_combine[i], "\n")
}
```

Finally, I write the result back to disk like this:

```r
writeLines(combined, path.expand("~/test3.txt"))
```

Now in my home directory I have this file:

**test3.txt**

```
I'm not a pheasant plucker, I'm a pheasant plucker's son
and I'm only plucking pheasants til the pheasant plucker comes.
```

Comment: It would be better to read them all in (e.g., `lapply`) and concatenate them *once* (e.g., `c`) then to iteratively build it. While with a simple list/vector it is not as big a problem, it is idiomatically better and parallels logic of not iteratively `rbind`ing data frames (which performs horribly due to repeated copying of the data)./

Comment: For instance, I'd like use `combined <- sapply(path.expand(c("~/test1","~/test2")), readLines)` (or `c(lapply(...))`, though in this example that's not an improvement).

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, you're right of course. My approach to this answer was to show a road to the solution using an idiom with which the OP is familiar. If speed is an issue, then it is a whole new exercise to think about why this method is slow, and how it could be speeded up.

Comment: @r2evans i.e. I got the impression that reading and writing data in appropriate formats, and understanding the difference between a data frame and a character vector were plenty for the OP to take away. Trying to get your head around an apply function might be asking too much at this stage? Or am I being too negative?

Comment: Allan, while your point is not without merit, there's also the point of learning R in its idiomatic form. In R, that often (certainly not always) involves operating on vectors and lists as a whole. Additionally, identifying *known-suboptimal* methods (iterative concatenation) is a good thing to do early in learning a new language. So while "keeping it simple" is certainly a good goal, I also think encouraging idiomatic methods is justified.

Comment: thanks a lot! this helped me a lot. I'm still an absolute rookie and while I thought that using a data frame was probably a horrible way to do this I also didn't know how else to do this, as all examples I found of people merging texts were using this. Obviously because they had statistical data but I thought I might as well try it
PS: I'd like to upvote but I can't do that yet